# move in file- unix

Tags: shell, unix

For example consider this dataset:

tomato     1kg

orange     2kg

Fruit      Quantity

I want my dataset to be as:

Fruit      Quantity

tomato     1kg

orange     2kg

How can I use commands?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` and its hold space to accomplish that:

```
sed -n -e '${p;x;s/^\n//;p}' -e 'H' yourfile
```

- on the last line (`$`), print it then print the content of the hold space (i.e. all lines except the last one)

  - the `s` command is necessary because the `H` command adds a newline to the hold space, so the hold space starts with an empty newline
- append to the hold space (`H`)

Answer (score 0):

If you’re reading from a file, this will do what you want:

```
(tail -1 myfile && head -n -1 myfile) > newfile
```

Put it in parentheses to combine the output from both processes.

If you’re not reading from a file, it’s more difficult. You may have to
send part of it to a temporary file.

Answer (score 0):

When the order of the other rows are random, you can use

```
tac inputfile
```